# Multiple Linq (Extension Method) Joins With Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, linq, join, anonymous-types, inferred-type

In C#, I'm attempting to do multiple extension-method joins, in which the second join is with an enumerable of an anonymous type produced by the first join:

```
List<Contact> filteredContactList = GetFullContacts()
    .Join(GetContactCompanyRoles()
        , ct => ct.IdContact
        , ctCmpRole => ctCmpRole.IdContact
        , (ct, ctCmpRole) => new { Contact = ct, ContactType = ctCmpRole.ContactType })
    .Join(GetContactRoles()
        , ctf => new { ctf.Contact.IdContact, ctf.ContactType }
        , ctRole => new { ctRole.ContactId, ctRole.ContactType }
        , (ctf, ctRole) => new { Contact = ctf.Contact, PrimaryInd = ctRole.IsPrimary})
    .Select(rec => rec.Contact)
    .ToList();
```

ct and ctf.Contact is of Type Contact.

I am, however, getting the following error when attempting to compile:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join...' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type argument explicitly.

Is there a way to get around this error without having to create an actual class for the anonymous type from the first join? Are there other options that I am not considering?

Comment: I would recommend writing the linq statement with query syntax instead as it is both easier to read and write (in my opinion).

Comment: I much prefer the extension methods, I personally find them much easier to read.  Also a nice feature of using extension methods is that you can break these into multiple lines of code in order to get a clearer error message from the compiler.

Comment: Ahhh... that old argument. "Method syntax vs. Query Syntax" (I'm a query syntax person for Joins .. method syntax when no joins are required .. ).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I do use both but `Join` and `GroupJoin` I feel is quite messy to write in lambda.

Comment: If you break this into several discrete statements, can you then pinpoint which Join is triggering the compiler error?

Comment: It's giving me the compiler error on the second join

Comment: You write "ctf is of Type Contact" but isn't ctf actually referring to the anonymous class that is projected by the first join?

Comment: You're right, I modified the question.

Comment: It looks like it specifically doesn't like the join clauses in the second join. There's something about the fact that it's joining using two anonymous objects. Is it that the compiler sees these two objects as ultimately different types, therefore rendering it unable to do a comparison evaluation? Is there a way to define a comparison?

Comment: My understanding is that should work as long as each member of each anonymous type has the same type and name.

Comment: Ah, I see. For the sake of brevity in my question, I standardized the names of the properties for ctf and ctRole.

ctf has the property for contact ID as ctf.Contact.IdContact and ctRole has the property for contact ID as ctRole.ContactId

It's compiling now when i put this in my anonymous initializer:

new { ContactID = ctf.Contact.IdContact ...
new { ContactID = ctRole.ContactId...

Comment: ah, that explains why I could not find where the mismatch was!  Glad it worked out for you, I also added that into my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice an apparent typographical error here:

```
    , ctRole => new { ctRole.IdContact, ctRole.ConatactType }
```

where perhaps you mean this:

```
    , ctRole => new { ctRole.IdContact, ctRole.ContactType }
```

i.e. use ContactType instead of ConatactType.

---

After this was resolved, through comment / chat we determined that compiler errors were still occurring because some of the anonymous classes being used to set up the multi-key joins did not have the same member names.  In other words, instead of:

```
   , ctf => new { ctf.Contact.IdContact, ctf.ContactType }
    , ctRole => new { ctRole.ContactId, ctRole.ContactType }
```

The member names needed to be normalized between the two anyonymous classes:

```
   , ctf => new { ContactID = ctf.Contact.IdContact, ctf.ContactType }
    , ctRole => new { ContactID = ctRole.ContactId, ctRole.ContactType }
```

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Vincent Ugenti, it was determined that the compiler could not evaluate the two anonymous types in the join clause arguments for the second join due to a mismatch in property names. When adding

```
ContactID =
```

to both of the anonymous initializers, the code was able to compile.

```
.Join(GetContactRoles()
    , ctf => new { ContactID = ctf.Contact.IdContact, ctf.ContactType }
    , ctRole => new { ContactID = ctRole.ContactId, ctRole.ContactType }
    , (ctf, ctRole) => new { Contact = ctf.Contact, PrimaryInd = ctRole.IsPrimary})
```